# bytes - quotes or not?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-invocation, bytes32

I have a contract with a function that takes as parameter a `bytes32`, and a mapping that uses a `bytes32` as key.

In geth, it seems like I can call `contract.foo("0x123abc")` and `contract.foo(0x123abc)`, but I'm not sure they give the same results.

Same for `contract.mymap("0x123abc")` and `contract.mymap(0x123abc)`, are they the same ? Are they always processed as `0x123abc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` ? Bytes are similar to strings but I'm not sure of the difference.

---

I can't test anything I want on my contract, but I checked and both `map(0x1234567890abcdef123)` and `map("0x1234567890abcdef123")` work but give different results. Which one should I use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use quotes. JavaScript has a maximum integer precision of 64 bits. This means that if your number is over 8 bytes, and you type it in without quotes, you will immediately lose precision.

For example:

```
0x1122334455667700 - 1
> 0x1122334455667700

0x1122334455667700 - 0x1122334455667701
> 0
```

The correct way:

```
web3.toBigNumber("0x1122334455667700").minus(1).toString(16)
>'11223344556676ff'
```

`bytes` and `bytes32` are actually very different. `bytes` is identical to `string`, whereas `bytes32` is identical to `uint256`.

If your function is expecting a bytes, web3 will interpret your string as ASCII, i.e. "12345" will be interpreted as "\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34". If it's expecting a numeric type (i.e. `bytes32`), it will interpret the string as a BigNumber. If you want to be sure and reduce ambiguity, you can manually convert your numerics to BigNumbers using `web3.toBigNumber()`.

For example, if you're having issues with `'0x123abc'` try

```
web3.toBigNumber('0x123abc')
```

instead

Comment: '0x123abc' with quotes is causing different behavior for the OP. So I suggest decimal quoted '1194684'. Is there something better?

Comment: edited to show example

Comment: Good idea, already upvoted your answer but will include your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good explanation. The loss of precision explains why I get different results ! I oversimplified, actually the mapping give the same value for `0x123abc` and `"0x123abc"` but it's different with longer numbers, like `0x584832ca31d3f972b95d2f53`. I didn't think of that so I simplified my example, but now it's edited to be more accurate.

Comment: I don't do any mathematical operations on them, but now it's clear it's precision loss when I do : `web3.toHex(0x584832ca31d3f972b95d2f5300000000)` and I get `"0x584832ca31d3f6f94f4ed2610a400000"`. On the other hand, `web3.toHex()` with quotes works like expected.

Answer (score 3):

From the [ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI):

- `bytes` is right-padded with zeroes (to a length of 32).  "0x123abc" with quotes is `bytes`.
- types like `bytes32`, `uint`, `int` are left-padded with zeroes (to a length of 32).  0x123abc without quotes is a number (in base 16).

Since the contract takes `bytes32`, use 0x123abc without quotes or its decimal equivalent 1194684 to reduce confusion with hex.  (To be safe, use quotes for '1194684' so that it's interpreted as a BigNumber.)

EDIT: Per @Tjaden To use '0x123abc', use web3.toBigNumber('0x123abc').

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know bytes32 was equivalent to BigNumber. What is hex then ? I have long hex values I store I'm the blockchain, it seemed easier to use bytes as they're written as hex.

Comment: You should essentially always use quotes. When you don't use quotes, the number is immediately converted to a JS number, which has a maximum precision of 64 bits. When you use quotes, web3 interprets it as a bigNumber, which is almost always preferable

Comment: @TeleportingGoat `bytes32` is just a 256-bit number and number-wise hex is base 16.  Data stored in the blockchain is binary, which is more compactly viewable as hex: that hex could be interpreted as a number, a string, or just as a raw blob of data.  I'll update answer to emphasize that '1194684' should be in quotes.

Comment: "use 0x123abc without quotes" this will lead to a loss of precision as well. JS will just immediately convert it to a 64-bit type

Comment: @TjadenHess Good point but '0x123abc' with quotes is causing different behavior for the OP.  So I suggest decimal quoted '1194684'.  Is there something better?