# How do I check for empty bytes array?

Tags: bytes, solidity-0.7.x

In 0.7.6 I want to check if a bytes array is equal to "" or not, but the compiler doesn't like

```
bytes fingerprint = "";

if(fingerprint!=""){
// do something 
}
```

How do I check for this?

Answer (score 1):

bytes is a dynamic array of byte, maybe you wanted to uses bytes32 instead ?

[What is the difference between bytes and bytes32?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/what-is-the-difference-between-bytes-and-bytes32/11771)

or just check the array length of that array.